# Angular state/router with url params not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, state

I am having difficulty loading up templates using state and parameters.

The below code works great when I navigate to /contacts

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        url: '/contacts',
        templateUrl: 'views/resources/contacts.html',
        controller: 'ContactsController'
    })
```

When I try and navigate to /contacts/123 I use the below piece of code.

**Edit:** I am only using the below piece of code and the only difference is I add in the "/:id" to the url.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        url: '/contacts/:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/resources/contacts.html',
        controller: 'ContactsController'
    })
```

This is when I start running into problems. The page won't load and I get a console error that says I can't instantiate the module app [(link to angular site from console error)](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.6%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:24:186%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:23:252)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:23:495%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:37:427%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:37:275)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:41:35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js:19:463)

Can someone help me out? I am not sure why my when I try and use params everything starts to break :(

Comment: both state have the same name

Comment: have you enable html5mode, if not the url should add # before eg. #/contacts #/contacts/:id

Comment: First thing to do is switch to the un-minified version of `angular.js`; the error message will be more verbose. I wish they'd add this to their doco as it would help solve most initial problems

Comment: @stalin - I am only using one state & route. Both bits of code are there to display the differences (I made an edit as well)

Comment: @JerryChen html5mode is enabled - the first piece of code works perfectly but when I add "/:id" I get the error

Comment: maybe a naming conflict? You tried changing contacts/:id to something else like kontact/:id? what does it do?

Comment: @LouisXIV - swapped the name and still got the same error "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that when I added the "/:id" my calling of script src files on my index.html page were not being called properly. I had an extra . in front of the path, resulting in my angular files, services, directives etc.. not being loaded/called properly.

I went from this:

`<script src="./app/app.js"></script>`

to this:

`<script src="/app/app.js"></script>`

Thanks to everyone who helped out on this!

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the params in your .state definition like so:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts', {
    params: { id: null },    // note null is the default value if no param is specified
    url: '/contacts/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/resources/contacts.html',
    controller: 'ContactsController'
})
```